# How to use user-defined class instances/objects inside angular's controllers?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, three.js

I have written a class using **three.js** `threeDimView`, which contains my scene, camera, etc. I create a global object of this class `threeDimView_`, in my JS code.

```
threeDimView_ = new threeDimView();
```

Now I want to show some info related to this in another div.

How do I get this object - `threeDimView_` into my controller for this info div?

```
function infoController(threeDimView_, $scope)
```

If I pass it to the controller along with `$scope`, I get an error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: threeDimView_Provider <- threeDimView_
```

Comment: Why not to create it in your controller/scope? Like: `function infoController( $scope){ $scope.threeDimView_ = new threeDimView(); } `

Comment: If the object is trully global, then it is accessible inside the controller simply by its name, no need to inject it. Otherwise (or if you do not want global state) you could instantiate the object in an Angular service and inject this service to any other component that needs it.

Comment: @Cherniv: this is not good as it hinders unit-testing. The better approach is angular way (inject the object to the controller)

Answer (score 1):

I like @khanh's answer, but I might suggest using an angular factory, instead of a service.  Here's an example:

Without global scope:

```
app.factory('threeDimView', function(){
    return new threeDimView();
});
```

With global scope:

```
var _threeDimView_ = new threeDimView();
app.factory('threeDimView', function(){
    return _threeDimView_;
});
```

And then you can declare a dependency in your controller as such:

```
function infoController($scope, threeDimView){
    // use the threeDimView object (its already instantiated)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try configuring it as a service, like this:

```
var app = angular.module("yourapp",[]);
app.service("threeDimView",threeDimView);
```

Whenever you want to use it in a controller, just declare it as a parameter:

```
function infoController(threeDimView, $scope)
```

The idea to inject the object into controller instead of accessing a global variable or creating the object inside the function is to allow unit testing.